# Vegetable Grow time and watering Info Table

Tags: vegetables, fruits, water

I am building garden monitoring application and would like to find lists with

- growing time
- time to water
- period to plant

of at least the basic vegetables

Comment: Let us know once you have the app built.  i really like the idea.

Comment: Don't waste your time.  There is a boundary between human and the plants they want to grow/control.  There is no application possible that will water plants better than manual.  Once one understands their plants the different needs, grouping plants with like needs, lawn versus plant beds by watering via sprinklers and human involvement then it is possible to set timers to take over.  There is no way an application could or should take the place of humans interacting intimately with their garden with watering.  If we do not know our plants needs and set some timer to take care of all, doomsday

Comment: You'd have to go variety by variety, as even in one vegetable type there are varieties ranging widely in maturity time (for corn, from 60 day maturity to over 100). They also vary in water needs etc. not only that, but the soil they're out n will change the water requirements also. I have patches of ground right near each other where some need large quantities of water to grow a good crop, where the other areas don't. And the time to plant is different every year. Also changes from variety to variety. The best way is that do it manually from experience.

Answer (score 5):

This question comes up every so often on the forum, but I'm afraid you won't find such a thing. There are just so many variables that would make such an app impractical. For example, things that will affect watering time include (but are not limited to):

- temperature
- hours of sunlight (and note that while this is somewhat fixed by nearby trees and structures that block the sun, it can also vary from day to day due to clouds)
- soil texture
- proximity of other 'thirsty' plants
- plant variety

Some people do attempt to use a soil moisture monitor, which is more effective than an algorithm would be, but I think the general consensus there is that for most gardeners, there is simply no substitute to spending time in your garden and observing the condition of the plants.

Comment: #1 and #2 can be programmed into the app.  I do agree though that there is no substitue to spending time in your garden but in my opinion, an app like this one would give you a starting point if you are a new gardener (how much to water and for how long)

Comment: basicly it's not an app it's like a e-gardener. I don't want all the plants just the basic ones that could be found in a garden for start.I will monitor temperature,(also consider weather forecast for next day),sunlight sensor and moisture logging

Comment: I am firm about humans being able to manually know how to cultivate plants, any plants, completely manually.  This high tech stuff removes humans from the needs of their plants and gardens.  There is no benefit for this whatsoever.  Gotta do due diligence.  Gotta put in the time before trying to grow plants more artificially than we already do.  I think it is a hoot that those who have never grown a simple vegetable garden think they can jump into hydroponics.  Artificial mechanisms to determine WHEN to water.  And not understand the necessity for proper fertilizer and sunlight!

Comment: @stormy i just asked for same basic information not a detailed documentation of every plant in the panology,i do this project for fun in summer.Also i am from Greece every summer i go to my village where we have from watermellons to oranges and olives(also at least 50 chickens),so yeah i know some stuff....

Answer (score 3):

## 1: watering rule

Most efficient time to water is in the evening, to avoid water waste during the day. But it helps snails and slugs thrive. I prefer early morning right after collecting slugs.

## 2: growth period associated with water needs

Here is what I once used at home (units are gallons to water for a 5-foot row):

- [DS] stands next to plants that need a lot of water during dry spells.
- [CS] stands next to plants that need water at critical stages of development.
- [NF] stands next to plants that do not need frequent watering.

---

```
|Vegetable       [--]|  Critical time(s)                                                     |   Number of gallons of water needed                |
-----------------[--]| --------------------------------------------------------------------  | ---------------------------------------------------|
|Beans           [CS]| When flowers form and during pod-forming and picking                  | 2 per week depending on rainfall                   |
|Beets           [NF]| Before soil gets bone-dry                                             | 1 at early stage; 2 every 2 weeks                  |
|Broccoli        [NF]| Don’t let soil dry out for 4 weeks after transplanting.               | 1 to 1 ½ per week                                  |
|Brussels sprouts[NF]| Don’t let soil dry out for 4 weeks after transplanting.               | 1 to 1 ½ per week                                  |
|Cabbage         [DS]| Water frequently in dry weather for best crop                         | 2 per week                                         |
|Carrots         [NF]| Before soil gets bone-dry                                             | 1 at early stage; 2 every 2 weeks as roots mature  |
|Cauliflower     [DS]| Water frequently for best crop.                                       | 2 per week                                         |
|Celery          [DS]| Water frequently for best crop.                                       | 2 per week                                         |
|Corn            [CS]| When tassels form and when cobs swell                                 | 2 at important stages (left)                       |
|Cucumbers       [DS]| Water frequently for best crop.                                       | 1 per week                                         |
|Lettuce/Spinach [DS]| Water frequently for best crop.                                       | 2 per week                                         |
|Onions          [NF]| In dry weather, water in early stage to get plants going.             | ½ to 1 per week if soil is very dry                |
|Parsnips        [NF]| Before soil gets bone-dry                                             | 1 per week in early stages                         |
|Peas            [CS]| When flowers form and during pod-forming and picking                  | 2 per week                                         |
|Potatoes        [CS]| When the size of marbles                                              | 2 per week                                         |
|Squash          [DS]| Water frequently for best crop.                                       | 1 per week                                         |
|Tomatoes        [CS]| For 3 to 4 weeks after transplanting and when flowers and fruit form  | 1 gallon twice a week or more                       |
```

---

## 3: planting time

This will be good fun to implement these conditions in your application: you will have to cross them with the time your user planted the seeds or transplants; you may need to take a planting chart into account like below, which is very interesting and (even more) useful to gardeners:

[image: planting time chart]

PS: this chart is from  [BETTER HENS& Gardens](http://www.betterhensandgardens.com/making-2014s-seed-starting-planting-schedule-wdownloadable-template/), for **USA hardiness zone 6A**